# Как можно деструктурировать первый элемент в обьекте?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Можно ли как-то деструктурировать последний элемент из данного кода, чтобы не писать код по типу

```
const main = weatherData.weather[0].main
```

Вот код всей деструктуризации на данный момент

```
const {name: cityName, sys: {country}, main: {temp: temperature}, weather[0]:{main}} = weatherData;
```

P.S `weather[0] : { main }` именно тут хочу сделать лаконичный вариант деструктуризации.

Comment: Покажите как выглядит `weatherData`

Comment: что такое `weather`? Если это массив, то `weather : [main]`

Comment: weather - это объект. Но способ с weather : [main] подошел, а его можно еще в этом деструктурировании переименовать, что бы не было "main", а условно "mainInfo"